# Passive voice personal construction, when the main clause is in the Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice

When the main clause is in the Present Perfect, while converting it from impersonal to personal structure, it becomes Present Simple.

Example:
It has been reported that they have found the missing documents.
The missing documents are reported to be found.

Why can't it remain Present Perfect?

Comment: Where did you come across that rule? It doesn't sound familiar to me. "The missing documents have been reported to be found" seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: I would have said "The missing documents are reported to **have been** found", actually.

Answer (score 0):

> The missing documents are reported to be found

It is in the present case because the documents status of being reported to be found still pertains.

```
The missing documents were reported to be found
```

Implies that things have changed, perhaps it has more recently been reported that they are no longer found.